# Use system-property as the value of @WebAppConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

Is it possible to use a system-property for the value of the @WebappConfiguration annotation? I have tried something like:

```
@WebAppConfiguration("#{systemProperties['webapproot'] ?: 'war'}")
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all. Is there any other way to do this through spring? I don't want to do this through our build tools as it would break executing our integration tests from our IDEs.

Comment: using a $ instead of the # doesn't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. I wrote my own `ContextBootsTraper` by extending `WebTestContextBootstrapper` which Spring uses to load the `WebAppConfiguration`-Annotation value.

I extended the functionality to include a check if a certain system-property exists and overwrite the annotations value if it does:

```
 public class SystemPropTestContextBootstrapper extends WebTestContextBootstrapper {

    @Override
    protected MergedContextConfiguration processMergedContextConfiguration(MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
        WebAppConfiguration webAppConfiguration = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(mergedConfig.getTestClass(),
                WebAppConfiguration.class);
        if (webAppConfiguration != null) {
            //implementation ommited
            String webappDir = loadWebappDirFromSystemProperty();
            if(webappDir == null) {
                webappDir = webAppConfiguration.value();
            }
            return new WebMergedContextConfiguration(mergedConfig, webappDir);
        }

        return mergedConfig;
    }
}
```

This class can then be used with the `@BootstrapWith`-Annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(SystemPropTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("standardDir")
public class SomeTest {

}
```

This solution enables me to run the tests from my build-tool while maintaining the ability to run the tests from my IDE, which is great.

Answer (score 0):

`@WebAppConfiguration` doesn't seems to support neither SpEL nor placeholder resolving.

I checked it in the following way: I tried to inject system property and resolve placeholder using `@Value`. When I tried to inject a nonexistent property `@Value` failed throwing `SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'asd' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Properties'` and `IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'nonexistent_property' in value "${nonexistent_property}"` respectively while `@WebAppConfiguration`'s `value` had simply `#{systemProperties.asd}` and `${nonexistent_property}` intialized as simple `String`'s.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is unfortunately not supported.

The `value` supplied to `@WebAppConfiguration` must be an **an explicit resource path** as stated in the class-level JavaDoc.

If you would like for us to consider dynamic evaluation of the `value` attribute, please feel free to open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) to request such support.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)